# Groovy getAt() vs get()

Tags: groovy

Consider the list :
`def list = [1, 2, 3]`
If I use
`list.getAt(0)`
or
`list.get(0)`
Both will give the same output.
But is there any **difference between getAt() and get()**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#getAt%28int%29) explains it:

> Support the subscript operator for a List.

```
def list = [2, "a", 5.3]
assert list[1] == "a"
```

So there's no difference, but `getAt()` is the method allowing Groovy code to use `list[1]` instead of `list.get(1)`

See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading for how operator overloading works.

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#Operator-Overloading - suggested edit queue was full ...

Comment: As mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31076609/1108305), there is one key difference: `get` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the argument is out of range, but `getAt` will return `null`.

Answer (score 12):

The documentation doesn't explain this well, but what actually seems to be the difference in my testing is that `getAt(i)` will return `null` when referencing indexes not actually in the list, while the `get(i)` method will throw an *IndexOutOfBoundsException* when an index not in the list is passed in, just as plain old Java would.